# Defaulting to a value when a object property is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have an object (a return from a graphQl query), that I am iterating over in order to make the data structure simpler before using the data. There are some non-required field in the data model, and I would like to use the data when it's there, and default to undefined when it is not.

This is my current function:

```
const parseNovice = data => {
  return data.allContentfulNovica.edges.map(edge => {
    return {
      createdAt: edge.node.createdAt,
      id: edge.node.id,
      slika: edge.node.slika.file.url || undefined,
      tekst: edge.node.tekst.tekst || undefined,
      naslov: edge.node.naslov
    };
  });
};
```

The error I am getting is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null

In other words the file for the image is missing, and therefore the file property is not defined. Is there a way for me to default to undefined regardless of which of the properties in the chain is missing?

Should I be using a try/catch for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in a clean native way.  You would need to do `undefined` checks the whole way down.  You should consider how lodash impliments [`_.get()`](https://lodash.com/docs#get).  It wraps the logic for doing the `undefined` checks.  So you may want to consider using that or writing your own utility function if you find yourself doing these deep `undefined` checks often.

Otherwise you'll have to write something like this:

```js
let edge;

let thing = {
  prop: edge !== undefined && edge.node !== undefined && edge.node.tekst !== undefined && edge.node.tekst.tekst !== undefined ? edge.node.tekst.tekst : undefined,
  prop2: _.get(edge, "node.tekst.tekst")
}

console.log(thing); // undefined

edge = {
  node: {
    tekst: {
      tekst: "foo"
    }
  }
};

thing = {
  prop: edge !== undefined && edge.node !== undefined && edge.node.tekst !== undefined && edge.node.tekst.tekst !== undefined ? edge.node.tekst.tekst : undefined,
  prop2: _.get(edge, "node.tekst.tekst")
}

console.log(thing); // foo
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, decided to use lodash since I'm importing it anyway, forgot about the `.get()` function.